# Approver Details of PR in BitBucket from command line

Tags: shell, bitbucket

I have a requirement to get the approver details of a PR merged in the master branch of BitBucket. I would need to get those details from the command line and validate the approver details in my script. Could someone please suggest how would I be able to get the approver details of the PR from the command line similar to the PR activity from the console?

Thanks.

Comment: Bitbucket Cloud or Bitbucket Server?

Comment: Did you check https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/about-bitbucket-cloud-rest-api/?